# squid proxy to convert http requests to https

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

I am looking at achieving the following with squid proxy setup. When client sends a http request (say. http://, I would like my squid proxy to make this request into https and sends the request on behalf of the client and in turn will respond back to client unencrypted.

[client]---- http -----[squid proxy] --------https-----[server]

I would like to do this only for a certain set of URLS (dynamic list).
Can this be achieved?

Comment: you could give nginx a try. here you can rewrite request to https without the need of a proxy. even set of URLs is possibly, you can work with a matching list.